# Test binaries created temporary wrappers

Tags: autotools, libtool

In a project build and tested with autotools, I encounter the following behavior:

The test binaries located in the `.libs` folder, are created as temporary wrapper scripts. Their header contains some information

```
# cregions1 - temporary wrapper script for .libs/cregions1
# Generated by libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2
#
# The cregions1 program cannot be directly executed until all the libtool
# libraries that it depends on are installed.
```

Some, but not all, obtain the prefix `lt-` in front of their name. Therefore, these tests fail since no suitable reference output is found.

The above error message suggests that there might be missing dynamic libraries when the tests are built. However, I was not yet able to figure out which exactly these are and how I could include them easily. Does anyone have an idea how this could be solved?

Comment: What you seem to be describing is not consistent with what I observe in my projects.  What I see is that in an Automake project with Libtool, program targets themselves are built as wrapper scripts such as those you describe.  Then for each of the program targets, there are two actual binaries in ./libs, one with the `lt-` prefix and one without.  Do you indeed observe something else?

Answer (score 0):

> In a project build and tested with autotools, I encounter the
> following behavior:
>
> The test binaries located in the .libs folder, are created as
> temporary wrapper scripts. Their header contains some information
>
> ```
> # cregions1 - temporary wrapper script for .libs/cregions1
> # Generated by libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2
> #
> # The cregions1 program cannot be directly executed until all the libtool
> # libraries that it depends on are installed.
> ```
>
> Some, but not all, obtain the prefix lt- in front of their name.

If that's really what you see then something is badly broken in your project or with your Autotools.  But as I implied in comments, I suspect that what you see is actually somewhat different from your description.

Specifically, in an Automake project using Libtool, you should see that each compiled program target (designated via a `foo_PROGRAMS` variable) is built as a wrapper script such as you describe.  That is, the target *itself* is built as a script.  Additionally, two binaries are built in the corresponding `.libs` folder, one with an `lt-` prefix and the other without.  Again, `.libs` contains the *bona fide* binaries, not scripts, two for each program target.<sup>*</sup>

> Therefore, these tests fail since no suitable reference output is
> found.

You should not be trying to run the binaries in .libs directly.  You should be running the corresponding wrappers, instead.  They are, after all, what you specified should be built.<sup>**</sup>  They serve to launch the real binary, in such a way that library dependencies are satisfied, especially dependencies on uninstalled shared libraries included in the same project.

You may recognize that this is roughly analogous to how Automake + Libtool builds shared libraries: the artifact designated in the Makefile.am is a "libtool archive", with extension `.la`.  This is a metadata file that references other artifacts that get built in `.libs/`.

> The above error message suggests that there might be missing dynamic
> libraries when the tests are built.

It's not an error message.  It's a comment explaining (part of) the reason for the wrapper script.

> However, I was not yet able to
> figure out which exactly these are and how I could include them
> easily. Does anyone have an idea how this could be solved?

If in fact your build is producing the expected artifacts, according to the pattern I describe, then you seem to be going out of your way to make things hard on yourself.  You should be able to run the built binaries via the wrapper scripts.  This is precisely their purpose.  The idea is that they transparently hide the complexity of running uninstalled binaries (which may include RPATHs and other fun things), including those that rely on uninstalled shared libraries belonging to the same project (which in many cases would not by default be discovered by the dynamic linker).

If your build is **not** producing the expected artifacts and pattern then you are probably doing something that interferes, such as playing games with symbolic links or providing custom rules that muck with the contents of `.libs/` (perhaps unintentionally).

---

<sup>*</sup>Perhaps fewer binaries would be built for each target under some circumstances, but under all circumstances you should see that `.libs/` contains only real binaries, not wrapper scripts.

<sup>**</sup>By which I mean that the wrapper scripts are built with the names and locations you designated for the wanted targets.  Presumably you don't have in mind that scripts such as those would be installed on the system when you `make install`, and indeed you don't get that.  `make install` will install the real binaries.